# What is the command to put the current window in half the screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, window

I want to put the current, active window on one side of the screen. Then ideally I could put one window on the left half, and one window on the right half.

On windows the keyboard shortcut (the only method I know) is the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> to specify the left or right side of the screen.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a recent Ubuntu version with Unity then with the mouse you can the non-maximized window and drag it to the left or right. When you see the orange outline, let go of the mouse. Or, for the full window, drag up to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 12.10 Unity you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>(num keys)</kbd>. 
Eg.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> for full size screen;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> for horizontal half screen on right,
- same works with <kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> & <kbd>6</kbd> also.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04 you can click the top of the window and drag to the side you need the window to use. drag it all the over and an orange box will pop up showing the area it will cover.